# expressJS : middleware based on regex

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I have a problem routing using the regex matching feature in expressJS 4.

I want to use `app.use()` to define what routes are available for the url not starting by `/api`

**routesWebAuth.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var webAuthenticationCtrl = require('controllers/web/auth.js');

router.post('/auth/login',   webAuthenticationCtrl.login);
router.get('/auth/isLogged', webAuthenticationCtrl.isLogged);
router.get('/auth/logout',   webAuthenticationCtrl.logout);
```

**app.js without regex**

```
function routeinfo(req, res) {
  console.log("matched : " + req.path);
  next();
}
//we accept all routes
app.use('/', routeinfo, routesWebIndex);
```

For the request `localhost/auth/login`
it returns : `matched: /auth/login`

**app.js with regex**

```
function routeinfo(req, res) {
  console.log("matched : " + req.path);
  next();
}
var regex_notApi = /^\/(?!(api))/;
//only the route not starting by /api
app.use(regex_notApi, routeinfo, routesWebIndex);
```

For the request `localhost/auth/login` it returns : `matched: /`

The problem is, in the case where I use the RegEx, the route `/auth/login` is not matched as the router is provided with the url `/` instead of `/auth/login`. how can I fix this ?

Comment: Maybe this: `^\/(?!api).*`

Comment: Tried it already, same problem

Answer (score 1):

I know it is too late but I think this regex would work:

```
/^\/((?!api).)*/i
```

```js
app.use(/^\/((?!api).)*/i, myFunc);
```

This matches `/`, `/auth`, `/auth/login`, `/foo`, `/foo/bar` and ...
And it does not match `/api`, `/api/`, `/api/foo` and ... 
Be noticed that it also does not match `/apibar/foo` which I don't know is your use case or not.

Also you can test express regex routing here: http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/